# ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to check error for my web app, I tried to register and I can't register user. How should I solve this error?

"ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

[image]

#### UserRequest.php

```php
        $rules = [
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'password'  => 'required|min:6',
            'password_confirmation' => 'filled',
        ];

       if ($this->password_confirmation) {
        $rules['name']      = 'required|max:20';
        $rules['email']     = ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user()->id)];
        $rules['password']  = 'required|min:6|confirmed';
        }
        return $rules;
```

#### UserController.php

```
    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
    $user     = new User;
    $name     = $request->input('name');
    $email    = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $params   = [
      'name'      => $name,
      'email'     => $email,
      'password'  => Hash::make($password),
    ];
    if (!$user->userSave($params)) {
        return redirect()->route('user.create')->with('error_message', '');
    }
    if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
      return redirect()->route('user.signin')->with('error_message', '');
    }
    return redirect()->route('bbs.index');
    }
```

Comment: According to the error message, `$this->user()` is null

Comment: "$rules['email']     = ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id)];"
I coded this and it seems okay so far. what you think?

Comment: By “it seems okay” do you mean the error went away?

Comment: yes, error went away.

Comment: Then as long as the logic does what you expect it to be doing, you should be okay. Unfortunately I don’t know what those variables, what they resolve to, and what you expect them too.

Comment: I got it. thank you @Chris !